# Pass variable to awk or store only the first field

Tags: bash, awk, cut

I have a data file that I need to filter based on the value of the first field (row 0 column 0). For example, with this data:

```
123 test1
123 test2
321 test3
321 test4
451 test5
```

I need to generate this output:

```
123 test1
123 test2
```

So I need some way to store only the first field and match against it in `awk`. The problem is `awk` code is run for every line so that variable is always overwritten. Is the solution to cut the first field then store that in a variable and match against that in `awk`? If so, can you provide an example of that?

The problem with this code is it doesn't print the first match, and it will update `field` so that it will print other undesirable matches.

```
awk -F"  " '
$1 == field {
        print; 
}
$1 != field {
        field = $1
}
' data.txt > awkOutput.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk`'s default field separator is sequence of space so you don't need to set `-F"  "`. Since you are only interested in the first field of first line, use `NR` variable which holds the line number.

The following `awk` one-liner does what you need:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{ field = $1 }$1==field' file
123 test1
123 test2
```

`NR==1` is an pattern that gets executed for the first line only. We set variable `field` to `$1`. The next pattern checks if first column is equal to our variable. If it matches, it returns a truth value. In `awk` the truth value triggers default print of the line.

Answer (score 0):

if it doesn't have to be done fully in awk I'd suggest something like that:

```
grep "^`head -1 data.txt | awk '{print $1}'`" data.txt > Output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help but you can try this too:

```
 awk 'BEGINs{FS=" "} $1=="123" {printf( "%s\t%s\n", $1, $2)}' input.txt
```

if the first field matches "123" (i.e. $1=="123"), the output will print the first and second field (with a tab in between (i.e. \t)), and it will start a new line (i.e. \n).